# How to control flow of execution of statements in node

Tags: node.js

In this program the statements `uploader = req.body.uploader; location = 'assets/posts/' + req.file.filename; console.log(uploader+"  1  "+location);` in postUpload()  are executed after completion of all statements execution in uploadPostHandler(), i don't know why??

```
async uploadpostHandler(req, res) {
    const postStorage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req,file,cb) => {
            cb(null,POSTS);
        },
        filename: (req,file,cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    });
    const postUpload = multer({storage: postStorage}).single('post');
    let post = {
        type: 0,
        noOflikes: 0,
        noOfcomments: 0,
        likedBy: [],
        comments: [],
        shares: 0 
    };
    var uploader = "";
    var location = "";
   postUpload(req,res,(err) => {
        //console.log(req.file);
        //console.log(req.body);
        if(err) {
            res.status(501).json({
                error: true,
                message: 'Internal Server Error1'
            });
            console.log(err);
        }
        uploader = req.body.uploader;
        location = 'assets/posts/' + req.file.filename;
        console.log(uploader+"  1  "+location);
    });
    try{
        post.uploader = await uploader;
        post.location = await location;
        console.log(post.uploader+"  2  "+post.location);
        const result = await PostQueryHandler.savePost(post);
        if(result == null || result == undefined || result == "") {
            res.status(501).json({
                error: true,
                message: 'DataBase Error'
            });
        }
        else{
            res.status(201).json({
                error: false,
                message: 'SuccessFully Uploaded'
            });
        }
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(501).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Internal Server Error2'
        });
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The one parameter you're passing to `postUpload` (i.e. `postUpload(<stuff in here>)`), is a function that is being called at a later point in time. The flow of execution jumps from the `postUpload` line straight to the `post.uploader = await uploader;` line. I don't know what `multer` does, but it will be calling your callback function when it has a result (i.e. asynchronously), which is why the line mentioned in the original question are called last - they're the last lines of the callback, which is called after the execution of the rest of the code.